# Will a winter-damaged hosta self repair?

Tags: plant-health, hosta

In winter, the next-years growth spikes of some of my Regal Blue Hostas got trampled off, and now that they're up, the leaves all have blunt-ended, ragged ends that curl and ripple. This is right by the house, and I would like to know whether I can expect them to self-repair in a reasonable amount of time (like under a year), or should I plant something in front of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existing leaves won't heal this year. New ones will be fine.

This is true for most leaves: damage is not repaired.
Leaves [decrease in efficiency](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3599711?uid=3739448&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=47698889087207) as they age so from the plants point of view why invest more energy in an older leaf when a new one will yield a better return.

Edit: if you remove old leaves from a vigorous healthy plant it will not weaken it. I grant that if you remove every leaf from the plant that is a set back.  It depends on the overall percentage of damaged leaves. If all are damaged take one or two at a time every few weeks.

Comment: If I remove the old leaves, will it grow new ones, or would It weaken the plant too far?